What are the true normalized cointegration vectors in R (ca.jo, cajorls and VECM functions) and how to interpret them?
I'm struggling with understand the difference between (and why there is this difference) the normalized cointegration vectors provided by the ca.jo function and the ones provided by cajorls and VECM (tsDyn package) functions.
Those are the results from ca.jo function, with the cointegration vectors normalized for the first variable LSELIC (the test returned r=2, LSELIC.l1 and LIBCBR.l1 are the two vectors of coefficients from that cointegrations relationships):

The cajorls function "Returns a list object with elements of class lm for the restricted VECM and a matrix object with the normalized cointegrating vectors".

Ultimately, the VECM provides the same results of cajorls function:

So, what is the "correct" normalization? Or, what I believe, what are the interpretations of these two normalized cointegration vectors for the same variable?

Is the difference not that one is restricted and the other is unrestricted? That would seem to be an obvious answer.

Right. I dind't understand the meaning of "restricted" in cajorls and VECM functions, since ca.jo function already provided a normalized vector for the first variable (LSELIC). Could you explain it?

I do not remember what that means (if I ever knew). If you cannot find the answer in the help file of cajorls, consider contacting the author of the R package.
